# Chrome Dev Tools Randomly Switching Values

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I edit CSS in the dev tools, I encounter this odd bug where let's say I change a width from 1200px to 980, it will randomly snap back to 120, 0r 90, or some other random number like 89.

In terms of my setup I'm on Windows 7, running chrome 46.0.2490. We use Grunt as our task runner and have a custom setup. Nobody else at the office is having this issue.

I dug around stack overflow but couldn't find anything related to my specific problem. Hopefully someone has an idea as to what the problem is. An interesting thing to note is it somehow is related to the original value, wether it is a multiple of the original value, or one less etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've had a similar problem but where the CSS property value won't change whatsoever after I type a value in, and nothing short of restarting the tab will fix the problem.

Comment: If you can reproduce this reliably, we'd like the bug to be filed at crbug.com/new  Thank you